# Akka Ask & Futures

Tags: akka, spray

I'm an akka noob so apologies!

I'm playing around with a system that uses Spray and Akka.
I'm using the following code snippet to send a message to another actor.
It uses ask which, from what I understand will return a future which is resolved in "mapTo" and "map". I then return the result to the users using Sprays "complete" directive.

```
val response = (worker ? Create(json))
            .mapTo[Ok]
            .map(result => s"I got a response: ${result}")
            .recover { case _ => "error" }

complete(response)
```

My question is, since this is a future, do I need to be worried about sending the correct response to the client? In some code samples I see examples where the actorRef to reply to is sent as part of the request...

```
// set reply to actor
val replyTo = sender() // important to not close over sender()

// create actor that collects replies from workers
val aggregator = context.actorOf(Props(
    classOf[StatsAggregator], words.size, replyTo))
```

Then in the receiving actor...

```
replyTo ! SendResult
```

Should I be passing the "replyTo" actor as part of the request or is this all taken care of in the mapTo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `replyTo` idiom only matters if you are sending the message in the callback of a future.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate on that a bit? How does complete know when to run and ensure it is replying to the right client with the right message? Does it block???
Also, say in the receiving actor, it in turn delegates the job to a child actor. Do I then have to use the "replyTo" idiom or could I again use the same pattern as above (mapTo) to control the response coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `complete` directive will send back a response to http/https client of your service. You don't need to do more than that. Please note that your code swallows errors by making `recover` on a future. Spray will treat it as a success and will return status code `200`.

The last and most importantly, your worker has to reply with `Ok` message back like this.

```
class Worker extends Actor {
    def receive: Receive = {
        case Create(json) => 
        //do some staff with json
        sender() ! Ok // This Ok message will be passed in the future in spray route
    }
}
```

The `replyTo` idiom is needed only when worker uses Future internally to process the work load. As it in the following example

```
class Worker extends Actor {
    def recieve: Recieve = {
        case Create(json) => 
            val future = Future{
                //do some staff with json
            }

            val replyTo = sender()

            future.onComplete {
                case scala.util.Success(result) => 
                    replyTo ! Ok
                case scala.util.Failure(ex) => 
                    replyTo ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(ex)    
            }
    }
}
```

The `replyTo` is needed to fix actual sender of the message since `onComplete` may be executed within a different actor context that can point to a different sender resulting in message being sent to a wrong actor.